# Error on drag and drop action on protractor typescript, Argument of type '"{x: 540, y: 504}"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILocation'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

i need help on this one, i'm encountering this error on my drag and drop action on typescript. Any idea how to fix this one?

```
browser.actions().
  mouseDown(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').
  mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 540, y: 504}').
  mouseUp().
  perform();
```

Error occured:

```
Argument of type '"{x: 540, y: 504}"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILocation'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ILocation](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angular-protractor--angular-protractor/interfaces/webdriver.ilocation.html) Interface is `{x:number,y:number}` but you trying to set string

**changes:**

```
browser.actions().
  mouseDown(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').
  mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 540, y: 504}').
  mouseUp().
  perform();
```

**to**

```
browser.actions().
      mouseDown(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').
      mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), {x: 540, y: 504}).
      mouseUp().
      perform();
```

.
.

Comment: mouseDown(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').single quote is still needed for mouseDown since its parameter is string